# how to get html data from 1 website for about json file in flutter

Tags: flutter

280/5000
I'm writing an app that read "Yesterday's" story with flutter. How to get data from the website "https://mylifengayhomqua.blogspot.com/2012/04/ngay-hom-qua-tung-chap-1.html". Specifically, get a list of chapters, chapter names, chapter contents for a listview.

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to download the HTML code which you want to parse. You can do it by adding to your code a function like this:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart';
import 'package:html/parser.dart';
import 'package:html/dom.dart';

...

Future initiate() async {
  var client = Client();
  Response response = await client.get(
    'https://mylifengayhomqua.blogspot.com/2012/04/ngay-hom-qua-tung-chap-1.html'
  );

  print(response.body);
  return response.body;
}
```

There's a nice article about scraping HTML, you can find it [here](https://itnext.io/write-your-first-web-scraper-in-dart-243c7bb4d05).

Then you have to find the right HTML selectors and parse the response.body in this way:

```
var document = parse(response.body);
  List<Element> yourContent = document.querySelectorAll('your selector');
```

Converting to a map should be easy then and is nicely described in an article above.
Good luck <3

Comment: Thank you very much, can you do a project and put it on github for me to consult?

Comment: You do a project and I can look at it, but I don't want to promise help as I'm not a professional dev

Comment: Sorry, I don't have time to finish your work for you for free. Also I don't want to open unknown .zip files from strangers.